# Change owner of file uploaded in server

Tags: file, ftp, joomla1.5, cpanel, ownership

I have trying to overwrite or perform some file operation to the files uploaded in a webserver.

Previously I have uploaded the files from joomla extension. It defined its owner as 99. Without changing its owner it my login name i am unable to perform file operation using ftp and cpanel.

what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the FTP layer of Joomla.

It does depend a bit on how your hosting sets permissions (whether they use ACL's, etc), but the FTP layer of Joomla is designed to get around exactly this issue.

Documentation for this feature is here:
http://help.joomla.org/content/view/1941/302/1/2/